# force browser to re-cache cdn

Tags: html, caching, cdn

If a resource is located on my server (say `/js/somefile.js`), I sometimes do things like `<script src="/js/somefile.js?v=3" type="text/javascript"></script>` and update `v` whenever changes are made to ensure a user's client doesn't use the old cached version.

What should be done if using a CDN resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CDN resources should have a version in the URL. For example Google's CDN URL for JQuery 2.1.4 is https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js.
If the version of JQuery changes so should the path to the new version.

Comment: Makes sense.  Thank you